# What is the difference between PCI_VDEVICE and PCI_DEVICE?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, pci

What is the difference between the PCI_VDEVICE and PCI_DEVICE macros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working inside the kernel, the code *is* the documentation actually. Here, you're a lucky man as both macros are documented (not always the case). It looks like they are equivalent, except that `PCI_VDEVICE` is less verbose.

Proof:

[PCI_DEVICE](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/pci.h#L808)

```
/**
 * PCI_DEVICE - macro used to describe a specific PCI device
 * @vend: the 16 bit PCI Vendor ID
 * @dev: the 16 bit PCI Device ID
 *
 * This macro is used to create a struct pci_device_id that matches a
 * specific device.  The subvendor and subdevice fields will be set to
 * PCI_ANY_ID.
 */
```

[PCI_VDEVICE](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/pci.h#L850):

```
/**
 * PCI_VDEVICE - macro used to describe a specific PCI device in short form
 * @vend: the vendor name
 * @dev: the 16 bit PCI Device ID
 *
 * This macro is used to create a struct pci_device_id that matches a
 * specific PCI device.  The subvendor, and subdevice fields will be set
 * to PCI_ANY_ID. The macro allows the next field to follow as the device
 * private data.
 */
```